# Spring STS doesn't recognize 'pointcut' keyword

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to create a simple aspect but my STS doesn't recognize the 'pointcut' keyword. I've installed all AspectJ plugins available but it made no difference.

Does anyone have I idea how can I get around this?

Thanks and Regards,
Cristian

---

My aspect looks something like this:

```
public aspect LogAspect {
    pointcut method() : 
        (target(com.example.Class1)
        || target(com.example.Class2) )
        || execution (* com.example.controller.*.*(..));

}
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know STS, only Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA. But STS is Eclipse-based, so I guess I know what went wrong.

Have you maybe created the aspect via "New -> Class" instead of "New -> Aspect"? Then the file extension is *.java instead of *.aj. Just rename the file ion the console or in some kind of file manager (Windows Explorer or similar), then it will compile.

---

**Update 2016-02-06 13:48 CET:** Assuming you have correctly installed AJDT, as you said, it looks as if you created a Java project instead of an AspectJ project. If the AspectJ nature is missing in your project, the nomal Java compiler will not recognise the aspect and show exactly that error message. Only the AspectJ compiler can parse AspectJ syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. The file extension is `.aj`

Comment: Then maybe AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) are not installed correctly, but this is pure speculation now. Maybe it helps other STS users to help you if you show more of your aspect than just `<PREDICATE>`. If you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and maybe screenshots from what the error looks like in STS, the probability for a good answer will be higher.

Comment: The project wasn't created by me, I've just imported it. Is there a way to add the AspectJ "nature" to the project, after import?

Comment: Right click -> Configure -> Convert to AspectJ project did the job. Thanks a lot for the tip!